# Nav Bar - Script explain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

I know this is embarrassing... but can some one explain me what exactly this script do line by line.

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-navbar ul li > a', 'click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.ui-navbar').find('a').removeClass('ui-navbar-btn-active');
    $(this).addClass('ui-navbar-btn-active');
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show().siblings('.content_div').hide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-navbar ul li > a', 'click', function () {
```

When someone clicks anywhere on the page, check if the target was an anchor tag (`<a>`) directly below a `<li>` inside a `<ul>` inside an element with the class `ui-navbar`.

```
$(this).closest('.ui-navbar').find('a').removeClass('ui-navbar-btn-active');
```

`$(this)` is now the anchor tag - the script is going to find the closest element with the class `ui-navbar` in the DOM tree and remove the class `ui-navbar-btn-active` from all anchor tags beneath it in the DOM tree.

```
$(this).addClass('ui-navbar-btn-active');
```

Then it will add the class `ui-navbar-btn-active` to the anchor tag the user clicked on.

```
$('#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show().siblings('.content_div').hide();
```

This assumes the anchor tag has an attribute called `data-href` which matches another element's ID. Example, the user just clicked on `<a href="http://www.google.com" data-href="google">Google</a>` and the script wants to find `<div id="google">whatever</div>`. If it finds the element, it will show it (jQuery prefers setting the css to `display:block` for this) , then grab all the sibling elements in the DOM tree which have a class of `content_div` and hide them (`display:none`).

Essentially what is going on is the page has some nav links - whichever one you click on gets an active class, and all the other nav links lose theirs. Then it shows some content the user expects to see specific to that nav link, and hides any other content that may be visible from a previous click.